# How to choose which fragment to open from specific activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My mainActivity contains 5 fragments which you can switch through with tabs. The main tab shown on start is the third one (the one in the middle). I have a button in fragment #1 which opens activityTwo. What should I put in the onBackPressed method in activityTwo in order for it to bring me back to mainActivity with selected tab #1. I currently have this, but it opens mainActivity and shows the main tab (#3)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
    ActivityTwo.this.finish();
}
```

How can I make it show tab #1 instead of tab #3?

Comment: use an intent, it could be a boolean checking if the button has been pressed or not, before you set the adapter to #3 check if it has been pressed..if yes then go to tab #1 | if you plan to have more buttons for other activities you  could use a number in your intent assigning it every time from which fragment you opened the each activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first activity should still be on the activity stack, so you should not call `startActivity` again. Instead, you can use `setResult` to pass a value back to your first activity:

```
// Inside your second activity
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
```

Then, from your first activity, replace `startActivity` with `startActivityForResult`, with a request code (any integer you want, as long as it's unique):

`startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);`

Then override `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Code to select tab 1 here
            // mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: So I need to set the result to OK in onBackPressed so it can be set when going back to the mainActivity. And also instead of startActivity, I should use startActivityForResult with intent and request code?

Comment: @N.Park Yep, that's correct. I edited my answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using view pager , so while you return from activity 2, use **viewPager.setCurrentItem(page)**;

where page will be your tab no, (in this case it will be 2, since it starts with 0). Hope this helps, if not then please clarify a bit more.